# How can I populate a tableView with a parse dictionary?

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am trying to populate a tableView with a parse dictionary( containing a string and a location ), I am managing to upload the data to parse and download it to the console , however I am having a lot of trouble adding it to my tableView, the place is added like this(in a map view):

```
let geoPoint = PFObject(className: "location")

geoPoint["location"] = activePlace
geoPoint["spot"] = places
geoPoint.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succes, error) -> Void in
    print("place has been saved")
}
```

and it is downloaded / added to the console like this:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "location")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) in
    
    
    if error != nil {
        
        print(error)
        
    }else {
        
        print(object)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The full code of my tableView is this:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

var rideSpots = [""]

//test start

//class Place {
//    var ACL : String
//    var location : String
    
 //   init(ACL : String, location : String) {
 //       self.ACL = ACL
 //       self.location = location
 //   }
//}
//let places2 : [Place] = []
//test stop

var places = [Dictionary<String,String>()]

var activePlace = -1

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func companyNameUpdatedAlert(title: String, error: String, indexPath: Int) {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
            
            textField.placeholder = "Enter new text"
            
        }
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            
            let lat = places[indexPath]["lat"]!
            
            let lon = places[indexPath]["lon"]!
            
            places.removeAtIndex(indexPath)
            
            places.insert(["name" : alert.textFields![0].text!, "lat" : lat, "lon" : lon], atIndex: indexPath)
            
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(places, forKey: "places")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            
            
        }))
        
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        
    }
    
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        
        let changeText = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Change spot name" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Void in
            
            self.companyNameUpdatedAlert("Update text", error: "enter text below", indexPath: indexPath.row)
            
        })
     /*
        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Void in
            
            places.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            
            tableView.reloadData()
            
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(places, forKey: "places")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
 
        })
        */
        return [changeText]
        
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        
            
            super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //retrieve the data from parse start
        
        let query = PFQuery(className: "location")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) in
            
            
            if error != nil {
                
                print(error)
                
            }else {
                
                print(object)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                
            }
        }
        
        // retrieve the data from parse stop
        if places.count == 1 {
                places.removeAtIndex(0)
                
                places.append(["name":"GO to map to add spot","lat":"90","lon":"90"])
            }

            if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("places") != nil {
                
                places = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("places") as! [Dictionary]
            }
        }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        
        didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        
    }
    
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        
        return 1
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return places.count
        //return places2.count
        
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = places[indexPath.row]["name"]
        //cell.textLabel!.text = places2[indexPath.row].location
      
        
        return cell
        
        
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
        
        activePlace = indexPath.row
        
        return indexPath
        
    }
    
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "newPlace" {
            
            activePlace = -1
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        
    tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This sounds easy but for some reason I can't figure it out so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to save the places you receive from the API. Where you say `print(object)`, did you try adding `places = object` (before calling reloadData!)

Comment: When I do that it tells me "Cannot assign value of type['PFObject]?' to type ['Dictionary<String, String>]' @Bensge

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to create an object to represent smaller parts of the larger PFObject, I would recommend you create a places struct

```
struct Places {
    var someData: String!
    var someMoreData: String!
}

//Class level variable of places
var places: [Places]?
```

Then, when you receive your object from your query, you can create your place and append it to the array.

```
var placeToAdd = Places(someData: object["name"], someMoreData: object["anotherField"])
places.append(placeToAdd)
```

Finally, when creating your cell, you can access the information appropriately.

```
cell.textLabel!.text = places[indexPath.row].name
```

Comment: The idea in question works. The example I gave was just that, an example. It was meant to demonstrate how you could implement something similar in your project, not meant to be copied and pasted and be a solution.